# Nodejs/Apache config for proxy pass

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy

I want to use Nodejs/Apache proxy pass to serve my APIs, but after add below apache(httpd) config, it seems that config not working.

OS:

```
CentOS 6
```

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
 
   DocumentRoot /home/MyUser/public_html
   <Directory />
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
 
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
   </Proxy>
 
   <Location /api>
      ProxyPass http://MyVpsIp:1337
      ProxyPassReverse http://MyVpsIp:1337
   </Location>
 
</VirtualHost>
...
```

after:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Open example.com/api in the browser:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /api was not found on this server.
```

**EDIT:** 
when I open `example.com:1337/api` in the browser, everything is ok! but I want `example.com/api`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to proxy by using Location, following should work for you.

```
  <Location /test>
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3001/  retry=0 timeout=60 keepalive=On
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3001/
  </Location>
```

Firt question is how will use your URL?
**example.com/api** or **example.com/api/smthng**

If you will use api between slashes like /api/  you need to specify it in Location tag like following

/test to /test/

```
  <Location /test/>
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3001/  retry=0 timeout=60 keepalive=On
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3001/
  </Location>
```

And another point is as you see, I also added a / in the end of my ProxyPass (ProxyPass http:.....:3001/ ). So, if you share us some example URLs we may give the correct config for you case.

For example, in my example:
There is a VirtualHost listening 3001 port and there is a index.html (content is 'test') stored in the DocumentRoot. So if I browse :3001 , it will output test.

However, If I want to use **Proxy** (lets say this VirtualHost runs on port 88). So If I call  some_ip:88/test , it will return test **according to my first Location example**. 
And I need to call some_ip:88/test/ for my second Location example.

Comment: Thank you bro. This is an Example:
`http(s)://example.com/api/something => http://localhost/api/something`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this configuration for long time with no problems.

The difference is only in the thing, that I'm using `mod_rewrite`
to define requests for **Node.JS**, not `<Location>` definition.

It could proxy standard http/https request and also web sockets
to Node.JS application and back to client.

In example bellow - all requests starting with `/api` substring are redirected
by Apace proxy to Node.JS application running on the same computer on
`http://127.0.0.1:8888` (or on `ws://127.0.0.1:8888` for websockets).
If Apache Virtual Host is configured with `https://example.com/api`,
you need to use web socket address: `wss://example.com/api`.

```
...
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
...

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    # Virtual host basic configuration:
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com

    # Use mod_rewrite engine to select request for Node.JS:
    RewriteEngine on

    # Node.JS websockets requests proxy configuration:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /api/(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:8888/$1 [P,L]
    # Node.JS https requests proxy configuration:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api(.*)$
    RewriteRule /api(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8888$1 [P,L]

    ## ... any optional https certificates configuration after...
    #SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/...
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/...
    #Include /etc/letsencrypt/...
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/...
</VirtualHost>
```

Proxy tunnel will be created from `https://example.com/api` to
`http://127.0.0.1:8888`, but the unsecured communication is only inside
your webserver after proxy, so it's still OK.
In your firewall, it's only necessary to allow port `:80` (or `:443` for https)
in public zone. Not the port `:8888` for Node.JS - that port has to be protected.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing proxypass to add location and removing it's directory tag container.

```
  ProxyPass /api/ http://MyVpsIp:1337/
  ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://MyVpsIp:1337/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you bro. This is an Example:
http(s)://example.com/api/something => http://localhost/api/something